# catching errors if not valid

Tags: javascript, jquery

Supposed I have an input type text where the value of it is use as source in an image.

after clicking the button the image src should be replace with input text value, as of now I'm using

```
prevImgByUrl: function() {
   prev.imgPrevSrc.prop('src', prev.inputImg.val());
},
```

it is working fine but any idea how can I catch the error if the value is not valid (Http errors like 400, 500 etc)

Comment: Many html elements have an [`onerror`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#Image_loading_errors) attribute that you can attach a function to handle. `<img src="..." onerror="function()" />`

Answer (score 0):

You can have `onload` and `onerror` events bound to an image to check if the image exists.

Sometimes the on error method doest work as expected when the 404 page is returned with a 200 status or browser sometimes doesn't fire on error you can check on load event the width n height should be positive

So the image checker function returns a Promise either success/error you can have it work for you in your own way

```
function checkImage(src) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function() {
      if (!this.width && !this.height) {
        this.onerror();
        return;
      }
      resolve(src);
    };
    image.onerror = reject;
    image.src = src;
  });
}
```

Snippet/Usage attached below

```js
function showImage() {
  checkImage($('input:checked').val()).then(function(src) {
    $('.error').text('');
    $('img').prop('src', src);
  }, function(error) {
    $('.error').text('Something unexpected happend');
  });

}

function checkImage(src) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function() {
      if (!this.width && !this.height) {
        this.onerror();
        return;
      }
      resolve(src);
    };
    image.onerror = reject;
    image.src = src;
  });
}
```

```css
img {width: 50px;}
.error {color: red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="test" onchange="showImage()" value="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1155898826701639680/fnyfbU7B_400x400.png" /> StackOverflow

<input type="radio" name="test" onchange="showImage()" value="https://stackoverflow.com/images/not-there.png"> Invalid Image
<hr/>
<img />

<div class="error"></div>
```